# iOS calculator implementation dilemma: how and where to create the calculator stack

Tags: ios, properties

I came a cross a very nice calculator tutorial for Objective C/iOS. I have thought about this for a long time myself as well and was surprised they way it was implemented. It's very nice and elegant.

The tutorial first sets up calculatorbrain.h and calculatorbrain.m files that are meant to keep track of the calculator stack plus methods handling operations on that stack.

Then it declares a @property instance variable of that calculatorbrain class for the viewcontroller.

My questions is there seems to be a lot of ways to implement this. Why would this way be better?

1) A simple alternative would seem to be just to declare stack and stack methods within the view controller.
2) Instead of declaring it as a @property, why not just create an instance of the calculatorbrain within the view controller.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of the three ways? Which objective programming principle would provide a guideline in choosing which way is preferable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally a good practice to separate a logic from an interface.

For instance, if you decided to create another ViewController and make a transition to it from the original one, and you needed your calculation data there (for instance, if you would like to draw a graph), you would simply pass your calculatorbrain to the second ViewController.

You can read more about design patterns used in Cocoa framework (same principles apply to Cocoa Touch) here: [Cocoa Design Patterns](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW6).

Here is an Apple tutorial that provides a very thought-through, yet simple example of the MVC pattern application:
[Your second iOS app](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/Introduction/Introduction.html)

And you can search the web for more information about MVC (Model-View-Controller).

Comment: Yes, the reading is very helpful. Thank you. I doubt that I would have understood it though without going through the tutorials first.

Comment: I try to locate the Model Object Implementation Guide mentioned in the cocoa design pattern article but got a "page not found" message. Is it obsolete or is it somewhere else?

Comment: I'm glad that it helped :) As for the guide, unfortunately, I didn't read that one and I don't know why Apple removed it. I found it via google on third-pary sites. It is dated 2010, so, probably, it is simply outdated now.
You can have a look at Apple's "Your second iOS App" tutorial. It provides a thought-through yet simple example of the MVC patern application. I will add a link to the answer.
And actually, Apple's documentation is really great. And it has articles for programmers with different professional level. So have a look :)

Answer (score 3):

"There's more than one way to do this."

Although it's not specifically codified in `UIViewController`, one common pattern is that the model (whatever it is) gets pushed into view controllers (e.g. `NSViewController`'s `representedObject` property.) These days, the idiomatic way to do that would arguably be with a `@property` like this:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController

@property (assign) MyCalculatorModel* model;

@end
```

These days, with ARC and automatic property synthesis, you don't need to specify an underlying instance variable, so that's all you really need to do. Then when you create the view controller (presumably in your application delegate class or some other application level controller), the controller responsible for creating the view controller pushes the model into it using the property. (Note, it should also probably set the property to `nil` before releasing the view controller on teardown.)

Your option #1 is less desirable because it couples non-view code with view-specific code. Your option #2 is less desirable because it means that the view controller is responsible for somehow getting the model and putting it into the private instance variable itself, which is arguably an inversion of control. (i.e. you would prefer for something external to the view controller to push in the model, but it can't because instance variables are private by default)

Comment: Excuse me, I'm not too good at ARC. Should we really use `assign` in this case? Since it's not a delegate and we might need this object in the future, I would retain it. So with ARC it would be `strong`, I believe. What am I missing here?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the separation of task is to let viewcontrollers do all just the view related stuff but let each of the models handle the logic and results that the ViewController uses to display?

Comment: Can you explain the "inversion of control", the term rings a bell but I am not sure if I understand it correctly. Thanks.

Comment: @FreeNickname: Regarding strong/retain vs weak/assign -- You can use retain/strong if you want, but a retain relationship usually implies "ownership" (note there can be more than one "owner" in this sense). Since the ViewController doesn't philosophically "own" the model, it shouldn't need to retain it. The controller that pushes the model into the ViewController is probably the owner. If the model is going to be deallocated by that owner, that owner should *also* clear out the property on the ViewController (i.e. see it to `nil`) as part of its teardown process.

Comment: At a conceptual/abstract level, I think of the role of the ViewController as being "to control views." It should take the information it is given (the model) and construct (control) views to present the model to the user.

Comment: All I mean by "inversion of control" here is that in your option #2 the ViewController has to "go get" the model, instead of having it "supplied" by something else. It's the opposite of how I normally expect the operation to happen.  "Inversion of Control" also has a specific (related) meaning (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) but I could have just as easily said "in option #2 things are set up backward from how I normally would expect them to work."

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. I will keep it in mind as I learn a bit more.